# Android Google Maps onTap is not called

Tags: android, events, maps, call, tap

Somehow when I tap on the Icon I added to the Map the onTap Event is not called can somebody tell me why :S? Its a overlay with all Users I add to the Map they all have the same Icon but all diffrent Titles. But when I tap nothing happens I also tried Logging it if something happens with Log.d but nothing happens. This is the code:

```
private class MyUsersOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private List<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public MyUsersOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }


    public void addOverlayItem(int lat, int lon, String title, String... message) {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, title, null);
        addOverlayItem(overlayItem);
    }

    public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlayItem) {
        mOverlays.add(overlayItem);
        populate();
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index)
    {
        Log.d("Test Message", "It works");
        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);

        //Do stuff here when you tap, i.e. :
        //AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(cMainActivity);
        //dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        //dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        //dialog.show();

        Toast.makeText(cMainActivity, item.getTitle(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        if (shadow == false)
        {
            //cycle through all overlays
            for (int index = 0; index < mOverlays.size(); index++)
            {
                OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);

                // Converts lat/lng-Point to coordinates on the screen
                GeoPoint point = item.getPoint();
                Point ptScreenCoord = new Point() ;
                mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, ptScreenCoord);

                //Paint
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
                paint.setTextSize(10);
                paint.setARGB(150, 0, 0, 0); // alpha, r, g, b (Black, semi see-through)

                //show text to the right of the icon
                canvas.drawText(item.getTitle(), ptScreenCoord.x, ptScreenCoord.y+10, paint);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to post all the code where you fiddle with your mapview. OnCreate etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to put `mapView.setClickable(true);` in your `oncreate()` methode?

Answer (score 0):

It can be an issue if you want to click on an overlay AND have events for clicking on the general mapview.  If that is what you are trying to achieve then check out [this tutorial](http://androiddev101.com/episode-5-mapviews-and-overlays/).  Even if you are having a different issue the tutorial might help you fix your problem.

Comment: No I dont have any events for clicking on the general MapView

Comment: ok well not sure it may help then, but the tutorial shows you how to do both.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the code above, but somewhere else. You have another view stealing the `touch` events from your ´ItemizedOverlay`.

`Possibilities`

- You may be playing with `dispatchTouchEvent()` in your map activity and returning `true` all the time, informing that events have been used and no further dispatch should occour.
- In the layout where you define `MapView`, you may have added a view after `MapView` that is parcialy covering it. Motion events are dispatched starting from last added view.
- You may have added another `MapView` overlay that is covering the `ItemizedOverlay`.

Comment: No I am not playing with dispatchTouchEvent. No I am not having an other View covering the MapView. I have 2 types of Overlays the MyUsersOverlay and another Overlay for Buildings but on both the onTap Event does not work.

Comment: Post the code for the other overlay and the code where you create both of them, because on this one there is nothing wrong.